# How best to type "Any monad transformer stack containing m"

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'd like to write the function

```
fixProxy :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => (b -> m b) -> b -> () -> p a' a () b m r
fixProxy f a () = runIdentityP $ do
  v  <- respond a
  a' <- lift (f a)
  fixProxy f a' v
```

which works just like you'd think until I try to run the proxy

```
>>> :t \g -> runRVarT . runWriterT . runProxy $ fixProxy g 0 >-> toListD
(Num a, RandomSource m s, MonadRandom (WriterT [a] (RVarT n)),
  Data.Random.Lift.Lift n m) =>
 (a -> WriterT [a] (RVarT n) a) -> s -> m (a, [a])
```

where I use `RVarT` intentionally to highlight the existence of the `Lift` class in `RVar`. `Lift` represents the existence of a natural transformation `n :~> m` which ought to encapsulate what I'm looking for, a function like:

```
fixProxy :: (Monad m, Monad n, Lift m n, Proxy p) 
            => (b -> m b) -> b -> () -> p a' a () b n r
```

Is `Lift` the right answer (which would require many orphan instances) or is there a more standard natural transformation MPTC to use?

---

Note the practical solution, as described in comments below, is something like

```
runRVarT . runWriterT . runProxy 
$ hoistK lift (fixProxy (const $ sample StdUniform) 0) >-> toListD
```

Comment: Is `runTVarWith` acceptable?  Also, have you tried giving it an explicit type signature?

Comment: Practically the issue is solved by using `fixProxy` as is and then `hoistK lift`ing it before the `(>->)`. I just encountered the `Lift` type on accident and wondered if it was possible to get a more general type.

Comment: The only other such type class I know of is the `MonadBase` type class from `transformers-base`, which I think is the one that most people use.